# Lighttpd mod_accesslog pipe process

Tags: lighttpd, access-log

I serve static files with Lighttpd and on every request I would like to log the MAC address of the client. For this I have been trying to use the `mod_accesslog` with a pipe logger, like this on the `lighttpd.conf`:

```
accesslog.filename = '|/path/to/python/script.py'
```

I pretend to execute the script that gets the MAC address and then write to a log.

Currently I'm getting a Lighttpd error:

```
2018-05-17 21:37:22: (mod_accesslog.c.180) writing access log entry failed: |/path/to/python/script.py Broken pipe
```

And the logging directory (which contains the python script) has the following permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 root www-data 4096 May 17 21:36 log
```

Also, if anyone knows, what is the format in which the parameters are passed to the (python) script? In case what I'm trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are no parameters to piped loggers.  lighttpd writes each log line to a pipe and the piped logger reads the line on stdin.

BTW, I don't know why you are trying to log the MAC, or from where you think you're going to obtain it.